Shelves for ~1.5 inch (~38mm) shower slide bar
We are looking for shelves for a shower slide bar. The slide bar is 1 1/4 inches in diameter.
We are in Canada (i.e. Home Depot, Home Hardware, Rona, Canadian Tire)
On Amazon, we found shelves for slide bars at a max diameter hole of 25mm but we likely need 31.75mm+: https://a.co/d/9DMT8IV
Advice is appreciated.



Check a plumbing supply store.

For a DIY solution, A U-bolt, a drill and a shelf(any) will work.
